# PHP include not working properly in XAMPP and WAMP changing source code causing stray tag issues

Tags: php

I have an interesting issue with webservers, hope you could help me with it. 
When I include php extansion files, though they appear in the source code but causing problems eg. stray tags. The interesting part is without include and include the source code seems exactly the same, however browsers and online validator give errors (and literally i dont see any difference between them).

Have anyone met with this problem before?
UPDATED with the source code!
Anyway it has to be a configuration problem since its working fine in the school.

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.php">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <aside>
            <div class="widget">
                <h2>Widgets</h2>
                <div class="inner">
                    Widgets
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>

<h1>Main</h1>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

content of included file:

```
 <head>
    <title>Weboldal neve!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css"/>
</head>
```

Here are the warnings the validator gives(these errors and warning are not showing up when i copy paste the included part only 2 warnings which is not that important, because the browser not complaining about them):

- Unable to Determine Parse Mode!
- No DOCTYPE found! Checking with default HTML 4.01 Transitional Document Type.
- No Character encoding declared at document level
- Info Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed
  Here are the errors the validator gives:
- Line 1, Column 1: character "!" not allowed in prolog
- Line 2, Column 1: no document type declaration; implying ""

  Line 5, Column 16: there is no attribute "CHARSET"
- Line 5, Column 23: required attribute "CONTENT" not specified
- Line 6, Column 46: NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES
- Line 7, Column 7: end tag for element "HEAD" which is not open
- i could go on there are 4 more but because of i assume its a config problem i wont go on now with them, ask if something is not clear, and needed additional informations

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using, the errors you are being given, and the code you are trying to include?

Comment: A validator should **NEVER** see your php code, unless your server is misconfigured. the validator should only ever see the OUTPUT of your code.

Comment: @Marc-B I havent said it sees my code. The thing is it gives different results for the source code included a file and the source code containing the included file (copied in).

Comment: You aren't giving anywhere near enough information. You need to update your answer to include your source code (As much as you think is needed in order for people to be able to help you) and also give information on exactly what "stray tags" are showing up. Otherwise there could be a 101 things that could potentially be wrong and no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @Rawb92 Anyway I thought i was clear about giving the basic problem (php include changing the source code somehow), if you need any additional information say it.
Here is the included file: <head>
 <title>Website Name!</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css"/>
</head>

Comment: Change `include` to `require` This will kill your page if for any reason PHP is unable to find and load `head.php` My gut feeling is that the file is either not in the same directory as this page or you have some error within `head.php` which is preventing it echoing out. Can you update your question with the source of `head.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: Encode in UTF8 without BOM...

Comment: And how did you achieve that? Might be helpful to other users to share your actual (code) solution.